# How to prove that L* is context free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar, formal-proofs, formal-grammar

Let's say we have a language of form: $L =$ {$a^nb^n: n∈N$}. I want to prove that $L^*$ is a context-free language. How do I approach this problem?

I know that $L$ generates CFG (context-free grammar) of form: $S→aSb$ ∣ $ϵ$.

On the other hand, I'm not sure what CFG does $L^*$ generate and generally how to prove that this is a context free language. I know that it will spawn words like $aabbaabbaabb...$ but don't know how to continue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already did half the work by creating a context-free grammar for L. Now ask yourself what exactly are the words in $L^*$? Any word in $L^*$ is of the form
$$w_1 \dots w_n$$
for some $w_i \in L$. So to produce words of $L^*$ we can do it in two steps. First we decide what $n$ should be. For that we have the rule

$$S \to SS$$

After that, you want to swap any $S$ with a word from $L$. How do you do this? You add another rule $S \to T$ and then have the production rules for your language $L$, in this case

$$T \to aTb | \varepsilon.$$

Those Rules ($S\to SS|T, \quad T \to aTb|\varepsilon$) are a context-free grammar for $L^*$. Example

Say we want to produce $a^3b^3aba^2b^2 \in L^*$. For that we first apply $S \to SS$ twice to get $SSS$, then apply $S \to T$ yielding $TTT$ and then, for each $T$ apply the last rules to produce each $a^nb^n$, giving $a^3b^3aba^2b^2$.

Comment: So if we find a context-free grammar for a language, that proves that this language is also context-free?

Comment: Yes, a language - by definition - is context-free, iff there is a context-free-grammar producing it.